# ZK using visible tag with @load

Tags: java, zk

I am using ZK.6.5.2 and ZK Bind with an implementation of the MVVM pattern.
In my ZK page I have

```
<h:label>Name:</h:label>        
<label value="@load(vm.person.Name)" />
<h:br />
```

I need the 3 lines above to be shown only if vm.person.Name is not empty but since  is evaluated at composition time while the @load value is populated at RunTime, To achieve the above I have

```
<h:label visible="@load(not empty vm.person.Name)"/>
```

But I am having to put the same condition on every component. Is there a cleaner way of achieving the same?

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.
John

Comment: Custom component perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a property to your ViewModel like this:

```
@DependsOn("person")
public boolean isVisible() {
  return true;  // your condition here  
}
```

and then use

```
<h:label visible="@load(vm.visible)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @bidifix but this would mean that I would still have to apply the 'visible="@load(vm.visible)"' condition to every line which is not really an improvement on what I have. Perhaps I need something like a hLayout that will control the entire section and I can apply the visible / not visible condition to that element.

Comment: @John exactly, you can use an arbitrary container element such as hlayout and add the `visible`-Attribute there

Comment: Thank you @bidifix. I am going to accept your answer based on all the effort you put in discussing this with me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
<zk if="@load(not empty vm.person.Name)">

<h:label>Name:</h:label>        
<label value="@load(vm.person.Name)" />
<h:br />

</zk>
```

or if you using "vm.visible" from above code

```
<zk if="@load(vm.visible)">

<h:label>Name:</h:label>        
<label value="@load(vm.person.Name)" />
<h:br />

</zk>
```